# canto feed-reader

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, rss

I want to install "canto" (rss-feed-reader running within the terminal). However I cannot install it as I cannot fetch it. My terminal says "Package canto cannot be found". Has anyone any ideas what to do?

P.S.: 
System: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)

Comment: Installation instructions are at http://codezen.org/canto-ng/source/#DebianUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`canto` is not in the official Ubuntu repositories. You have to get it somewhere else.

From the installation instructions at http://codezen.org/canto-ng/source/#DebianUbuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://codezen.org/debian xenial main"
curl http://codezen.org/static/canto-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-canto-curses
```

Comment: Tnx for your help. I did everything as I was supposed to. Yet my terminal says: "Packet python3-canto-curses cannot be found." Seems like I couldn´t add the repository.

Comment: My bad, I was on mobile and I messed up the first line. I will fix it as soon as I can.

Comment: @Rosika I have updated my answer. Please try again and let me know if it works.

Comment: Too bad. I could add the repository. It´s in the "/etc/apt/sources.list" alright. I did a "sudo apt update" as well. Yet when trying to install it the packet still couldn´t be found.

Comment: Huh, the `.deb` is definitely present in http://codezen.org/debian/xenial/.

Comment: I also did perform a "ping codezen.org" in order to test the mirror server and everything seems alright (0% packet loss). I´m afraid I have to let it go. Thanks a lot for your help anyway. Rosika

Comment: Worst case scenario: you can go to the link I gave and install it using `dpkg -i`.

Comment: O.K. "python3-canto-curses" and "python3-canto-daemon" are installed now. Still I can´t get canto running.

Comment: Edit: now I´ve got it running. Had to enter  "canto-daemon" and "canto-curses" without "python" in front. Thank you so  much for your help. Rosika